# Prefix the default table names for all liferay tables

Tags: liferay, prefix

Can I prefix all the Liferay tables that it initially creates by doing some configuration changes.

I am new to Liferay and analyzing it for my use.

I gather that new tables being created are prefixed to avoid any conflicts but I have a situation where it suits me better if its other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no for tables that Liferay creates on its first start. And as you have found yes for newly created tables using servicebuilder(uses the namespace tag)